# How to call method using onblur

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, method

i am trying to call a method using onblur, whether it is even possible or not, in my controller i m having search function that i want to call after when i typed any text inside input box and click outside it. please someone help me out.
here is my code and method..

```
<apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" onblur{!search}/>
```

method in controller-

```
 public void search(){  
     wrapProductList = new List<wrapProduct>();
     string searchquery='SELECT PricebookEntry.Name,Contract_Start_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,Full_Revenue_Date__c FROM OpportunityLineItem where PricebookEntry.Name like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' AND opportunityId =: opportunId Limit 20';  

      for(OpportunityLineItem priceBookEntryObject: Database.query(searchquery)) {
             wrapProductList.add(new wrapProduct(priceBookEntryObject)); //adding the searched products into list
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apex:actionFuntion`. Onblur of input call Action function using name
i.e. `searchAF`

This will call action function and Action function will call your search method.

Use rerender attribute to get updated value in view

```
<apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" onblur="searchAF();"/>
<apex:actionfunction action="{!search}" rerender="frm" name="searchAF"/>
```

Comment: what i have to put in place of frm in rerender

Comment: @RAT__ give Id to your apex:form `<apex:form id="frm">`